# Reformat textfile into one line string

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

This is an example file of what I have

```
1321|4
512|2
1056|2
314|16
69|1
239|2
0|0
0|0
0|0
0|0
534|0
```

But I need the file to be in a format like this:

```
1321|4|512|2|1056|2|314|16|69|1|239|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|534|0
```

I tried my luck with awk but I'm not getting an usable result, never used it before and can't get examples and manuals into working code. How can I achieve the needed format? Any Help would be awesome.

Comment: This works more or less, if I open it in Notepad on Windows I have the wished format, but in every other editor it's the same as before just with an extra | in front of the values. If i echo it to the terminal or use cat or so I get |0|0|22 as output

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
sed ':a ; N ;s/\n/|/g ; t a '
```

**Explanation**

```
 t loop  -- Loop continued until the substitution false or EOF occur .
 N       -- Get the two lines and stored in the pattern space .
```

`N` get the two lines and stored in the pattern space so the pattern space having two lines like `line1\nline2` then substitution perform like `\n` to `|` like `line1|line2` ,so the pattern space having one line and  loop continue  then get another one line and substitution perform.
Once `EOF` founded the loop terminated and print the pattern space .

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter,I had updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works more or less, if I open it in Notepad on Windows I have the wished format, but in every other editor it's the same as before just with an extra | in front of the values. If i echo it to the terminal or use cat or so I get |0|0|22 as output

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
tr '\n' '|' < file; echo
```

Or this:

```
awk -v ORS=\| '$1=$1 END {print RS}' file
```

Comment: `tr '\n' '|' < file` suffices. Also, this is answered exactly the same in the duplicate. Also, both solutions have the problem of missing a new line at the end.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks.  Newline can be fixed on `awk` like this `awk -v ORS=\| '$1=$1 END {print RS}' file`, but it still give an extra unwanted `|`

Comment: The tr version contains an extra vertical bar at the end --- don't know if that's an issue.

Comment: newline can be fixed by just echoing after. `tr '\n' '|' < file; echo`

Comment: @Jidder Thanks for info.  It still does not fix the extra  `|`, so my vote went to Jas :)

Comment: @Jotne could do this `tr '\n' '|' < file ;echo -e "\b "`

Comment: @Jidder It still prints one `|` unwanted at the end of the line.  It could off course be removed by another command, but its nicer and faster to get all in one.

Comment: `"\b "` removes the last `|`. Did you leave the space after `\b` in the command ?

Comment: @jidder my fault, did have a blank line in my test file.  ufff

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure awk is the best hammer for this nail, but

```
awk '{ printf("%s%s", sep, $0); sep = "|" }' sample.txt
```

should do it.

And here Jotne's improved version from the comments, adding a final newline:

```
awk '{ printf("%s%s", sep, $0); sep = "|" } END { print "" }' sample.txt
```

Comment: Adding an `END` section and it would be perfect. `awk '{printf("%s%s",sep,$0);sep="|"} END {print ""}'`

Comment: Shorter but not different enough for my own answer `awk '{ printf(NR>1?"|"$0:$0)}' test;echo` also removes the first bar that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Shell only (though it does require one sub-shell:

```
read -d '' -r -a lines < file
(IFS=\|; echo "${lines[*]}")
```